# Does a function which is oscillating have to have not-continuous derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

If $f(x)$ is a differentiable function  which is not $0$ everywhere  and has the property that around any interval around $0$, $f$ is neither fully positive or negative. Then it can be proven that $f(0)=0$.

An example of such a function is
$$\begin{cases}x^2\sin({1\over x}) & \text{ for }x\neq 0,\\ 0 &\text{ for }x=0.\end{cases}$$

All such functions I have seen so far satisfy this.

> Q: Is it true that the derivative of such a function cannot be continuous or is there a counter-example?

I feel that such a function exists and have tried a few examples but have been unable to find one.

Comment: Just take $f(x) = x^4 \sin(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=0$; it has a continuous derivative.

Comment: @Artic can you please explain close vote?

Comment: I think if you use something like $e^{-1/x^2} \sin(1/x)$, you can even make the function $C^\infty$.  (On the other hand, it would be impossible for the function to be analytic at 0: a power series with positive radius of convergence must be asymptotic to its first nonzero term, and thus must be either always positive or always negative on some interval $(0, \delta)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=x^3 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ has a continuous derivative and respect your criteria.